# About categories that are shown up in google search

Tags: seo, categories

I am pretty new in SEO, I am trying to understand how can I make google pop up the categories of my website when someone search and get results.

[image]

Comment: These are referred to as [sitelinks](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/sitelinks). We get this question quite often, so in most cases we mark them as a duplicate of the linked question above. We also have other questions on sitelinks [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=sitelinks+is%3Aq) (some of them are similarly marked as a duplicate of the linked question).

Comment: Thank you so much!